# Override all queries to a given model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible in Rails to override all queries on a given model regardless of the association they are coming through. Example:

I have a `Counties` model that is referenced by several models in my application. A `User` `belongs to` a `Country`, a `City` `belongs to` a `Country`, and so on.

Because the `Countries` table changes very very rarely and has small number of records I decided to cache the whole thing and whenever there is a lookup of a Country by ID in the application I want it to go through that cache instead of querying the database.

My caching code in the `Country` model looks like this:

```
after_save :expire_all
after_destroy :expire_all

def self.all_cached
 Rails.cache.fetch('Countries.all') { all }
end

def expire_all
  Rails.cache.delete('Countries.all')
end
```

Now, I would like to avoid going in every possible place in the application and changing the logic to make use of that cache.

I'm looking for a way for existing code like `User.country.name`, `City.country.name` to be handled in the `Country` model to make use of the cached values.

Is that possible?

**Update**

In other places of the application i will have `Country.where(:continent => 5)` `Country.where(:active => true)`. etc. I would like all of that be queried on the cached table instead of the real one. So I guess what I'm looking for is a way of defining in the model for all the queries to be executed on my cached object instead of the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just realized I don't really understand caching and it would take me more time to understand it than I'm willing to invest at this point. I apologize for answering without sufficient knowledge. I've deleted my answer in the hopes that someone else will respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of answering my own question... I didn't find a way to do exactly what I wanted, but what I did is override a `Country` getter method in every model that refers to it so that it goes through the cached variable.

**Additional method in the `Country` model:**

```
  def self.cached_coutry(id)
    all_cached.each do |country|
      return country if (country.id == id)
    end   
  end
```

**In associated models (`User`, `City`, etc.):**

```
class User
  belongs_to :country
  def country
    Country.cached_country(country_id)
  end
end
```

**Sidenote about performance of memcache on Heroku.**
I'm hosting the site on Heroku with the Memcachier add-on in the free plan. After implementing this solution I didn't notice much performance improvement as the call to the cache was taking similar time to the one required to execute this simple country lookup on the database. Therefore to squeeze out even more performance I've settled to store the whole list of `Countries` in the class variable instead:

```
def self.all_cached
  @@all_countries ||= Country.all
end

def expire_all
  @@all_countries = nil
end
```